# Android: SMS Database Update Receiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I'm updating sms status in sms database. Like this:

```
ContentValues StatusValues = new ContentValues();
StatusValues.put("status", 0);
StatusValues.put("type", 2);

ActivityContext.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms"), StatusValues, "_id = " + MessageID, null);
```

I want to learn its these changes. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that extends [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) then register it with your ContentProvider by calling the [ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#registerContentObserver%28android.net.Uri,%20boolean,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) method.

More information can be found in the Android Developer Documentation

Comment: Give me a running example please?